# Unit testing a plugin with a theme dependency

Tags: plugin-development, unit-tests

I wrote a plugin that adds functionality to load a content block (which is a page), and then passes it to a template part, which I did to avoid overloading the core WP global post. I'm trying to unit test it and wondering how I can map the `locate_template()` method to an asset in the test suite so it is not dependent on the current theme.

My test suite is setup like this:

```
/tests
 /assets
    block.php
  bootstrap.php
  test-view-plugin.php
```

And I am trying to map my class to load the `block.php` template part.

Comment: where is the test suite located? in the plugin directory?

Comment: in the end the plugin will have to work with whatever is the current theme, your question is unclear.

Comment: The test suite is located in the plugin, and it does need to work with the current theme, but I don't want it to be coupled with any particular theme so we can reuse it.

Comment: maybe you are looking for https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory (if it needs to work with child themes also) or https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory. in the plugin itself you can use relative paths with `dirname(__FILE__);`.